# Error Handling by display static HTML page

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to add functionality to my error handler by not only logging the message to the console, but by redirecting the client's browser to a static HTML page that would display some simple text content. Here is the existing handler:

```
var sql = require('msnodesql');

//store a connection to MS SQL Server-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sql.open(connStr, function(err, sqlconn){
    if(err){
        console.error("Could not connect to sql: ", err);

    }
    else
        conn = sqlconn;     //save the sql connection globally for all client's to use
});
```

I'm using express.js to create my web server. This is server side code. I want this to happen in realtime, as soon as the error occurs the client's web browser gets redirected.

EDIT: I guess what I really want to know is how to redirect the client's browser to a page from inside `if(err)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware that checks the state of the connection for each request and renders an appropriate template depending on the state (instead of using `res.render`, you can also use `res.redirect` or `res.sendfile`, of course):

```
var sql   = require('msnodesql');
var conn  = null;

sql.open(connStr, function(err, sqlconn) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Could not connect to sql: ", err);
    conn = false;
  } else {
    conn = sqlconn;
  }
});

// Express middleware that checks the connection state of the database
// connection: active, not yet active, or failed.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // database connection not active yet
  if (conn === null || conn === undefined) {
    res.status(503);
    return res.render('not-active-yet');
  }
  // database connection failed
  if (conn === false) {
    res.status(500);
    return res.render('db-connection-failed');
  }
  // everything seems okay
  next();
});
```

**EDIT:** forgot to mention that you need to include this middleware very early in the middleware chain, but certainly before any of your routes.

Comment: For whatever reason the page still won't render in the browser. The current page remains visible.

Comment: @gjw80 see my edit. You need to include the middleware very early on.

Comment: Can the sql.open happen after the middleware?

Comment: @gjw80 should be possible, yes. I did add an extra check for that to the code, though.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work. By the time it's evaluated to an error there's no more http requests going on. I need to type one in the browser manually or refresh the page to trigger one.

Comment: @gjw80 well yes, that's how HTTP works: it's a stateless protocol, once the request is finished, it's finished. You didn't write you wanted realtime notification when the connection to the database gets lost, which is – as far as I'm understanding now – what you *actually* want?

Comment: Yeah, as soon as the error is thrown I want the browser redirected to the '/unavailable' page. I am looking at `app.render()` and trying to see if that will work from inside the `if(err)` statement to do a browser redirect.

Comment: @gjw80 `app.render` can't help you with that. You should start looking at a realtime notification implementation like [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) if you want something like that.

Comment: Im already using socket.io in my web app, so just emit a message to the client with that and then have that redirect maybe?

Comment: @gjw80 possible, but you also need to monitor the connection for disconnect events

Comment: Looks like that worked, I just used sockets to emit a message to the client.