# app.render() not displaying in browser

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to use app.render() to display a jade file in the browser. In the following code, the html is displayed to the console correctly, but the browser never shows the related file.

```
app.render('unavailable', {title: 'Unavailable'}, function(err, html){
            console.log(html);

        });
```

EDIT:

I have this handler:

```
app.get('/unavailable', display.unavailable);
```

Then beneath this code in the same file (app.js) I have this:

```
sql.open(connStr, function(err, sqlconn){
    if(err){
        console.error("Could not connect to sql: ", err);

    else
        conn = sqlconn;     //save the sql connection globally for all client's to use
});
```

So, what I want to happen is when the `err` happens with the SQL connection, the `/unavailable` handler is executed and a static html page is displayed that says the service is down. However, because the error occurs on the server, and not the client, I don't have access to a `response` object at that time. I'm trying to artifically manufacture the client 'redirecting' to /unavailable in their browser to see the message.

Comment: What's `display.unavailable`? It probably is some kind of function. You have to alter it in a way I've described in my answer.

Comment: It is, and it has a res.render in there. However, '/unavailable' never gets executed (the handler) because the client browser stays on the same page. I'm trying to come up with a way to force the client's browser to redirect from the server.

Comment: Right, then in that case read Plato's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you don't send the html to the browser. Use `res.render` inside a route without callback, i.e.

```
res.render('unavailable', {title: 'Unavailable'});
```

or send the result of rendering like here:

```
app.render('unavailable', {title: 'Unavailable'}, function(err, html){
    console.log(html);
    res.send(html);
});
```

Read more about the difference here:

[What's the difference between "app.render" and "res.render" in express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403791/in-express-js-app-render-vs-res-render-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 0):

save a global `var sqlOK = false`, set it in sql.open callback, and redirect to `/unavailable` if you get a request while sqlOK is not true. you were also missing brackets around the else statement.

```
var sqlOK = false;

app.get('/unavailable', display.unavailable);

app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
  if(!sqlOK){ 
    return res.redirect('/unavailable');
    //return res.send(500) 
  };
  next();
});

sql.open(connStr, function(err, sqlconn){
    if(err){
        console.error("Could not connect to sql: ", err);

    } else {
        conn = sqlconn;     //save the sql connection globally for all client's to use
        sqlOK = true
    }
});
```

Comment: `'/unavailable'` handler should be set before `'*'` handler. Otherwise it will run into an infinite redirection loop.

Comment: I still have the problem where I can't automatically redirect to /unavailable. If a user logs on a page, then does something that requires a sql connection, the error occurs. The handler won't catch it until the page changes to any of the other handler cases. So, the user will be stuck on the same page without seeing the error page rendered.

Comment: if a user makes a request that causes you to make the sql connection (why aren't you making one at app start and keeping that one alive for all uses?) then it will be your responsibility to test for sqlOK within that route handler and redirect appropriately

Comment: [Hmmm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996299/error-handling-by-display-static-html-page/20999095).

Comment: App.render is one of the ways I'm trying to get that question to work, In using app.render it's not displaying what I expected, which is why I asked this question separately.

Comment: I'm not really sure what app.render even does. I thought res.render 'rendered' a web page visible in a browser. I thought that by saying `app.render('pageName')` it would basically do just that.

Comment: `res.render` generates html from a template, and sends the html as a response. you cannot display a page to a user, except as a response to a request. Thus my advice to test whether you can safely use the sql connection in a particular route handler (where you are preparing an appropriate response to a recently received request.) ensure you swapped the order from my original unedited post because that will prevent `unavailable` from being rendered. If you call `sql.open` inside a handler, put `res.render` inside the `sql.open` callback to delay the response until the async call completes.